# Rules based auto fill in Google Docs Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-docs

I am making a bookkeeping sheet.

The aim is to create rules, that search imported fields from our bank statement, and if a match is found automatically fill the adjoining cells with the rules data.

example:

Data:

```
HEAD - Imported Field       - Payees (autofill) - Account (autofill)
ROW1 - payment to JASON U   - from rule below   - from rule below
ROW2 - 234322 MERCHANT FEES - from rule below   - from rule below
```

Rules:(separate sheet)

```
HEAD - Matched Term - Payee     - Account
ROW1 - JASON U      - Jason Ure - Drawings
ROW2 - MERCHANT     - CBA       - Fees
```

We have this working in Excel now, but need to get it working in Google Spreadsheets. 
Anyone know how to convert this?

Comment: I figured a lot of the formulas would be the same or similar and anyone with excel expertise would possibly be able to offer some help.

Comment: what is where? I don't get this question. The rest i'm as unsure as you as to what is the appropriate use of tags. I would have thought it was ok.

Comment: Sorry @pnuts I think i know your question. The Rules "marched term" column has the term to search the "Imported Field" column. So if Jason U is found in the Imported Field list, then autofill the payee and account fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula works in Google Spreadsheet

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(SearchTerms,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(SearchTerms,C8)),-1,1)*(ROW(SearchTerms)-ROW(FirstTerm)+1))),SearchPayee,2,FALSE)
```

**Named Ranges:**

SearchTerms = G3:G7

SearchPayee = G3:H7

FirstTerm = G3

Comment: Accept your own answer. :)